# Route Workflow from a Pushbutton in Maximo

Tags: workflow, maximo

I am trying to have a Pushbutton in Maximo mimic the Route Workflow button from an automation script. In my case shown in the picture below, I want the Complete button to pop up the workflow and continue it. I have found things like

`wfs = MXServer.getMXServer().lookup("WORKFLOW")
wfs.initiateWorkflow("WFName", mbo)`

This only starts the workflow and does not do the same thing as the Route Workflow button in Maximo.

[image]

Comment: What is the node you are trying to advance? Is it an assignment node? A manual input node? One of the others? (The assignment section of the screen is for the work order app and doesn't have any bearing on the workflow position.)

Comment: @Dex it is triggering a manual input node in the workflow which is for the work order.

Comment: That sounds like what node the workflow would advance to. A manual input node prompts the user to pick something and then acts accordingly. That's not something it could be sitting on. What node is it on already, that you are trying to advance _from_?

Comment: Why doh't you just set the event of the button to ROUTEWF and the value to the name of the workflow process? Why do you need an automation script?

Comment: @Dex this is currently on a task node.

Comment: @Preacher I am doing more things than just ROUTEWF so I am trying to encompass everything that needs to be done when the button is clicked in one script

Comment: So can you have the workflow call the script instead of having the script call the workflow?

Comment: I only now realized you were doing this from an automation script but want the task completion dialog to still pop-up. I don't think you can do that from an automation script; I think that requires a bean class.

Comment: If you know which action the user would be taking in the task completion dialog, you can mimic the user taking that action in your script, causing it to advance to the next node down that path (the manual input node in this case). This is not exactly simple code though. It requires you to get the active instance of the specific workflow you want, get the list of assignments, then get the id for the one you want, get the list of actions for that assignment, get the id of the action you want to mimic, then "completeWorkflowAssignment" using that assignment id and action id.

Comment: However, I believe, since this came from an automation script (and those don't have a connection to the UI), that this would be considered not-interactive and therefore throw an error if it reaches a node that needs to open a dialog on the screen for the user to pick something (as you do with your manual input node). You should probably go with Preacher's suggestion instead.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than have the script initiate workflow, have an action line in the workflow that calls the script, via an Action Launch Point, and then proceeds to do what you want workflow to do. You could even then have another Action Launch Point on the same or a different script to do any follow-up processing. Then, you can hook your button to the workflow. That's basically how you're supposed to use Workflow, anyway: to choreograph your processes.